# How to shuffle or randomize an array such that the resulting array has sum of its elements always equal to fixed value in Swift 4.1?

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to shuffle an array of numbers and then store the resulting random array in a variable. But I want the resulting random array to have elements which always sum up to 1.

```
var numbers = [1,0.5,0.25,0.125,0.0625]
var newTime = [Double]()
var x = numbers.shuffled()

for _ in 0..<x.count {
            newTime.append(x.random_element())
        }
var sum = newTime.reduce(0, +)
for _ in 0..<newTime.count {
   if sum == 1 {
             print("Final Sum: \(newTime)")
        }
   if sum > 1 {
             let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(newTime.count)))
             newTime.remove(at: rand)
        } else if sum < 1 {
            newTime.append(x.random_element())
        }
}
```

EDITED: (following Duncan's suggestion)

```
var numbers = [1,0.5,0.25,0.125,0.0625]
var newTime = [Double]()
var x = numbers.shuffled()

for _ in 0..<x.count {
            newTime.append(x.random_element())
        }
var sum = newTime.reduce(0, +)
newTime.append(1.0 - sum)
print(newTime)
```

This works so long as (1.0-sum) is a positive number. In this case a positive number is appended to the array making the sum total of all the elements in the array =1.0.
However, if (1.0-sum) is a negative number then it does not work for me because the resulting newTime array will have all the previous elements in that array plus one more negative number which basically sums up to 1.0. In this case the resulting newTime = [0.125, 0.25, 0.0625, 1.0, 1.0, -1.4375]. Whereas I am expecting newTime = [1.0] as sum of rest of the elements is 1.4375, therefore, I need them to be removed from the newTime array.

Hope I am able to explain things clearly.

Comment: "therefore, I need them to be removed from the newTime array." What does that mean? When the sum of the array is >1 you want to remove items from the array? What if you pick 1.0 as your first item? Then the array is done with 1 element? (No, you are **not** explaining things clearly.)

Comment: let us say that the array I got using above (when 1-sum <0) 
[0.25,0.25,0.5,0.25,-0.25]. I don't want -0.25 appended to the array. Instead I need  one of the elements which is 0.25 to be removed from the array such that the final array would be [0.25,0.25,0.5], the elements of which would sum up to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Your goal is confused, and your code doesn't make much sense. You say you want to shuffle an array, but then you say you want the sum of the elements in the array to always add up to 1. The order of the elements in an array has no effect on the sum. It sounds like you want to create a random array of floating point values who's sum is 1.0, and then you want to randomize it.

Those are 2 different things.

If you're using Swift 4.2 you could create an array of objects where the sum is 1.0 like this:

```
var array = [Double]()

//create an array of values ranging from -2.0 to 2.0
for _ in 1...10 {
    array.append(Double(Int.random(in: -2000...2000))/1000.0)
}
let sum = array.reduce(0, +)

//Add one more value that brings the sum of the array contents to ≈ 1.0
array.append(1.0 - sum)
```

Then to shuffle the array just use

```
array.shuffle()
```

Due to the limitations of floating point, the sum of the array may not be **exactly** 1. You might get values like 0.99999999998 or 1.0000000004, but if you round the sum to 3 decimal places it will be `1.000`.

Comment: Thanks Duncan. I guess I was doing the other way round. that is I was first shuffling and then trying to check if the sum is 1. Let me try the way you put it. Will update if I am able to achieve desired results.

Comment: I have edited my question below. I have incorporated your suggestion but loos like I am still missing something. Please see my edit above. Thanks for your patience in helping me.